# Custom WordNet in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

So, I have an xml file that is formatted with as wordNet with Synsets and Synonyms and other tags. I need to use this xml file to get things like word similarites etc. So, I want to use nltk to read and convert this xml to a custom wordNet type of thing. I know I can use the XmlCorpusReader to create corpus out of xml, but I couln't figure out how to use the corpus to create the wornet and use functions like path_similarity etc. Is it possible to do this with nltk, if it is how should I proceed?

Thank you

Comment: Look into the methods at `from nltk.corpus import wordnet`, [More info](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)

Comment: @Jarad To be clear, I am not going to use the WordNet in nltk, I want to create a custom wordNet from my xml file, and use methods like path_similartiy in the link yo sent. I couldn't find something that I could use in there though,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the nltk utilities, you'd have to convert your xml format (owl?) to wordnet format, and then you can read in the corpus with the [WordNetCorpusReader](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html).